How to achieve alert suppression in Azure Loganalytic workspace and how dynamically we can activate after the suppression period?
We are using azuredevops pipeline to create Azure Loganalytic query based alerts across our envts and we have created well custom pipeline to loop through the parameters passing for each query items and will create each number of query with those query specific parameters. Below is the ARM template used to automate and the system works fine.
But still we are trying to enhance the alerts further wih below features and couldnt find any useful solution .
feature 1 -> capability to suppress the alert rules to specific period if the concerned team already addressed the issue to till the informed time and the alert should be activated once the suppression time is over. We read about of disabling and re-enabling the alerts, but that still have manual effort to mark enable and disable after tracking the time properly.
feature 2- . its my understanding is that When an alert is triggered, Azure Alert sends a JSON payload to the specified webhook endpoint. The payload includes information about the alert, such as the alert rule, the resource that triggered the alert, and the alert state (activated or resolved).We have payload already set to send information to our external monitoring system. looking for a way to create a Bug in the Azuredevops with the same payload information and assign to specific App teams.  This Bugs shouldnt recreate-if already active Bug is already present and, the occuracnce of these alerts should be auto populated to the Description part of the same Bug, n times its repeating.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "actionGroupName": {
            "type": "string"
        },           
        "query": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "logAnalyticsWorkspaceId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "AlertRuleName": {
            "type": "string"
        },    
        "tags": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "schedule": {
            "type": "object"
        },       
        "severity": {
            "type": "int"           
        },                          
        "operator": {
            "type": "string"         
        },  
        "threshold": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "autoMitigate": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": false
        },
        "enabled": {
            "type": "string"
        },        
        "customWebhookPayload": {
            "type": "object"
        },             
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "string"
        }    
},    
    "resources":[
        {
            "type":"Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
            "name": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",            
            "properties":{
                "displayName": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
                "description": "[parameters('AlertRuleName')]",
                "enabled": "[parameters('enabled')]",
                "source": {
                    "query": "[parameters('query')]",
                    "dataSourceId": "[parameters('logAnalyticsWorkspaceId')]",
                    "queryType":"ResultCount"
                },
                "schedule":"[parameters('schedule')]",
                "action":{
                    "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
                    "severity": "[parameters('severity')]",
                    "aznsAction":{
                        "customWebhookPayload": "{ \"AlertRuleName\":\"#alertrulename\", \"AlertType\":\"#alerttype\", \"Severity\":\"#severity\", \"Application\":\"#{appname}#\", \"Text\":\"#alertrulename fired with #searchresultcount records. #{alertDescription}#\", \"SearchQuery\":\"#searchquery\" }",
                        "actionGroup": "[array(parameters('actionGroupName'))]"
                    },
                    "trigger":{
                        "thresholdOperator": "[parameters('operator')]",
                        "threshold": "[parameters('threshold')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


Are you still facing the same issue. @Vowneee

Didnt get anyway to suppress dynamically from pipeline side without making the script running in backend
